Extract whole word in indesign with grep
I have a long list of words in a indesign file, one word per line.
Like so:
"Snake
Bottle
Cloth
Tonic
Ruler
Pothole
Congress"
I want to extract all words that contain the, say letter "n".
Please help.
Thanks.

The verb 'extract' makes me wonder, what exactly you're trying to gain? If you mean to remove all the rest words from the story with the GREP you probably have to do something contrary — to find all words that don't contain the letter 'n' and replace them with empty line ''

The following regex should do what you want:
(\w+)?n(\w+)?

See here: https://regex101.com/r/6d5q9m/1

Or \w*n\w* which is the same, as far as I understand (I can be wrong, though)

If you really want to extract the 'n'-words from a list of words I'd propose this GREP:
Find what: \b[^n]+\b
Change to: \n
The \b means an edge of the word. And the whole expression can be translated as: find any number of characters but 'n' within the word boundaries and change it to a break line.
If there could be a uppercase 'N' you can handle it with this modification:
Find what: \b[^N|^n]+\b

